# Use clojure to develop game server

Tags: clojure

I'm developing a server for a game. You kown in games,many data structures should be mutable. But Clojure's data structures is immutable. Is there some good idea to 
 do this? Should i use clojure for it?

Comment: The data structures may be immutable, but Clojure offers a number of mechanisms for maintaining state (see e.g.: http://lambdax.io/blog/posts/2016-04-18-state-management-in-clojure.html).  The question of whether you should use Clojure or not is probably too broad and opinionated to get a good answer here, but my point is that immutable data structures are not a reason to _not_ use it. When you finally do pick a language and hit up against some concrete programming problems you'll find lots of good help here on SO! Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mutating data structures allows you to squeeze the last ounces of performance out of your code, but given that you're writing a server, network latency probably has a much greater impact than memory allocations. Clojure should be suitable, certainly as a starting point.

While Clojure's data structures are immutable, application state can be managed via atoms, refs, core.async loop state, and data pipelines. A Clojure application is hardly static just because its data structures are.

The biggest risk you face right now is figuring out what to build, and Clojure's live development model will accelerate the learning loop. You can redefine functions while the server is running and see their effects immediately.

I suggest you prototype your server in Clojure, then, if performance gains need to be made, profile the code. If necessary, you can introduce transients and volatiles, and port performance critical sections to Java.